# Gutenberg block get recent pages

Tags: jsx, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

Based on the [dynamic block example](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/blocks/creating-dynamic-blocks/) for retrieving a recent posts block, I'm trying to create a block that retrieves pages.

In the php server component I changed:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
) );
```

to:

```
 $recent_posts = get_pages( array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
) );
```

and get a php error log:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as
>   array in mysite....:24
>
> 1. render_block_latest_pages(Array, '') /mysite/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg/lib/class-wp-block-type.php:108
> 2. WP_Block_Type->render(Array, '') /mysite/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg/lib/blocks.php:238
> 3. do_blocks('') /mysite/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286
> 4. WP_Hook->apply_filters('
>
>    apply_filters('the_content', '
>
>    the_content() /mysite/themes/bt-sass-blank-theme/template-parts/page/content-default.php:7

I also tried a normal query and it does not work. Gutenberg works with the Wordpress REST API, not sure if there might be an issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wp_get_recent_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) returns an array of post arrays by default, while [get_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) returns and array of page objects. If you're using the linked example verbatim, then you would need to replace `$post_id = $post['ID']` with `$post_id = $post->ID`.